# "No such file or directory" Error When Installing Google Cloud Platform Plugin on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to add Java 8 support to my Google App Engine project. To do this, I had to update Eclipse and thus install the newest Eclipse Google Cloud Platform Plugin. While the plugin had successfully installed the SDK, it still needed to install other tools. When it did that, it outputted:

```
[Installing Google Cloud SDK app extensions for Java]


Your current Cloud SDK version is: 198.0.0
Installing components from version: 198.0.0

+----------------------------------------------------+
|        These components will be installed.         |
+------------------------------+---------+-----------+
|             Name             | Version |    Size   |
+------------------------------+---------+-----------+
| gRPC python library          |   1.9.1 |   7.3 MiB |
| gRPC python library          |         |           |
| gcloud app Java Extensions   |  1.9.63 | 118.9 MiB |
| gcloud app Python Extensions |  1.9.69 |   6.1 MiB |
+------------------------------+---------+-----------+

For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

#============================================================#
#= Creating update staging area                             =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gRPC python library                          =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gRPC python library                          =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gcloud app Java Extensions                   =#
#============================================================#
ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  u'C:\\Users\\reddingBobulus\\AppData\\Local\\google-cloud-tools-java\\managed-cloud-sdk\\LATEST\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\google_appengine\\google\\appengine\\tools\\java\\jetty93\\jetty-distribution\\lib\\apache-jsp\\org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.18.v20170406-nolog.jar'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

My guess is that Windows is preventing the installer from installing Jetty because files must be put in the staging area, yet the max Windows file length prevents those files from being created. This comes from when I tried to install Jetty myself, yet could not because I could not rename the Jar to the proper name due to the max file length. However, that means that I either need to edit Windows to remove that "feature" or partition a part of my already fairly used up hard drive to Linux just to work. Is there anything else that I can do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That path does seem to be 265 characters (including the trailing `\0`) which is greater than the [maximum Windows path limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath).  But apparently this length restriction can be removed as of Windows 10 [by setting a registry key and rebooting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath).